# Past dates and futures dates in custom cell FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, calendar, fscalendar

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RhdA.png)

Can anyone help me, I use custom cell for selected dates to display icon and image etc. But past dates and futures dates label colors (when selected) are changing from gray to white , I want those dates still gray but in selected cell (custom cell).

and how you get dates that are past dates or future dates (that I mark )

Answer (score -1):

found the solution ,use `monthPosition`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32200252)

Comment: @tomerpacific: It looks like an answer to me. Though it would benefit from more explanation and context.

Comment: Self explanatory as it is. ```monthPosition``` give you dates detail that will display in cell. if it future or past you can set the title label color whatever you like.